# Varnish Multi-Site configuration with varying caching

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I have 3 groups of API's
Each of the 3 has a unique requirement for caching.

So group 1 can be cached "normally" as in just the URL matters.

Group 2 requires that an auth header is passed, so would like to cache them based on that header and url.

Group 3 generates responses based upon the UserAgent and url

Now I can easily do any of those on their own, but because all of the API's are "small" I would like them to share a cache system and reduce costs.

From what I understand using multiple vcl's and vcl.load in varnishadm would allow me to specify a custom vcl_hash (among others) for each.  Or is there a better solution as having an army of if statements just seems awful.

If I use vcl.load is there a way of having varnish automatically do this at startup so that the servers can be in an auto-scaling group?  (currently using systemctl)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for VCL Labels. Please check https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-separate.html or https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/one-vcl-per-domain for documentation and some examples.